# focus does not go to input after alert is shown

Tags: jquery

In the onblur of an input I make a test , and if the test fails then I go to a certain input :

```
<input type="text" name="login" id="loginAbonne" maxlength="25" value="<?php echo $data['user']['login'] ?>" <?php echo (isset($data['user']) ? "disabled" : "");?> onblur="verifLogin();" />
```

Javascript :

```
function verifLogin() {
    if ( mode == "ajout" && !loginDispo() ) {
        alert("<?php echo _getText('service.personne.tbr_title.login_existant'); ?>");
        $('#loginAbonne').focus();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the focus does not go to the #loginAbonne field after the alert is shown ! So how to refresh the page to make the focus go to the field ?

Comment: what's the result of `$('#loginAbonne').length`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function verifLogin() {
if ( mode == "ajout" && !loginDispo() ) {
    alert("<?php echo _getText('service.personne.tbr_title.login_existant'); ?>");
     setTimeout(function(){$('#loginAbonne').focus();}, 2);

  }
 }
```